# French: You know you hate the whole thing as much as I do

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

I'd like to express the following sentence in French.

> You know you hate the whole thing as much as I do.

My try is this. Is it okay?

> Tu sais que tu detestes toute la chose autant que moi.

Answer (score 8):

This is correct except for the missing **é** in **détestes**. However, I wouldn't say **toute la chose** (it does not sound good). Here is my suggestion (because you use "tu", I consider that this is not a formal sentence, therefore I use "ça"):

> Tu sais (bien) que tu détestes (tout) ça autant que moi.

Comment: Not only that *toute la chose* does not sound good: it sounds like a word for word translation of *the whole thing* by someone not talking French, when it's not at all what it means. You are right, *the whole thing* means *tout ça*.

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence is OK, but you could improve it a little bit.

If you clearly know what that thing is, you can say "cette chose" despite of "toute la chose".

To insist on the equality "as much", you can say "tout autant que moi" or "tout autant que je la déteste" (maybe a little bit long...)

That would give : "Tu sais que tu détestes cette chose tout autant que moi".

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Cette chose is that thing. The whole thing is not anything with chose.

Answer (score 0):

The adverb "tout" can be left out to build a more idiomatic sentence :

> Tu sais que tu la détestes tout **autant que** moi **dans son intégralité**.
>
> Tu sais que tu la détestes **intégralement**, tout **comme** moi.

Comment: That sounds like a literal translation.

Comment: Is there any literal translation? "the whole thing" and "as much as i do" have no obvious word for word translation.

Comment: Je pense que la confusion vient du fait que tu veux traduire *the whole thing* par *la chose dans son intégralité*, alors que "the whole thing" est une expression qui se traduit plutôt comme *tout ça*, *l'ensemble*. Ça ne fait pas concrètement référence à une chose que tu peux représenter par *la*. On dirait plutôt : *Tu sais que tu détestes tout ça autant que moi*.

Comment: This integralité thing is way off. As Simon says: whole thing is tout ça here.

Answer (score 0):

Tu sais que tu détestes tout ça autant que moi.

**Chose** does not work here in French, as Simon pointed out.

If you say **cette chose**, you are saying **that thing** and not the **whole thing** which colloquially is "**tout ça**".